# Where does body:hover apply to?

Tags: css, html, hover, transition

I have a design in which an animation is triggered when the user hovers over the window (the body element) like so:

```
body:hover .block1 {
width: 210px;
transition: width .2s;
}
```

The .block1 has a position:absolute attribute, and is inside of a container (also absolute). There is one other div (.parent) on the page with position:relative. So there are 2 main divs: .container and .parent.

When I hover over the body, the animation starts. However, when I hover over certain parts, say in-between the 2 divs or on the right margin of the container for example, the animation stops- as in it doesn't read it as a "hover" over the body. It is only on some small spaces around the page, seemingly random. What is going on here?

Comment: can you post a fiddle?

Comment: do you want the attributes of the hover stay when the mouse is out of the hover?

Comment: Here is a sample of the code: http://dabblet.com/gist/6048160
Notice how under the .container div and above the .parent div don't trigger the animation. I already set body margins and padding to 0 as well.

Answer (score 1):

When you are moving the mouse out from the block1 the animation stop, because you already not in 'hover'

The solution for this situation is only javascript

```
 $(".block1").mouseenter(function() {
      $(this).addClass('active')
}).mouseleave(function() {
 // you can enter code here if the mouse out of the .block1
});
```

**the css**

```
.active {
 width: 210px;
 transition: width .2s;
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention in the post this has to be pure css. And in my actual I am noticing now that the animation only works when I hover over the actual divs (which I didn't notice at first because they are big so they cover a lot of the page).

Comment: 'body:hover' is a bad idea, because all the page is body it's always will be hover, if you want for specific div use .block1:hover{} (notice that hover is not work on ie6 but no one care nowadays about internet-explorer 6

Answer (score 0):

Apply the animation to all elements which "don't work" one by one or use the `*` selector.